# Riemann like sums for Lebesgue integrable function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f(x)$ be a non-negative function on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x) \ dx=1.$ Actually, f(x) is a probability density function for a continuous random variable.

Can I justify that 
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{m \in\mathbb{Z}} \frac{1}{n} f(\frac{m}{n}+\frac{z}{n})= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \ dx
$$
where $z \in [0,1]$ is fixed. I am trying to use Lebesgue Dominated convergence Theorem but which function should I pick up as a dominator to justify the exchange of limits and integrals ?

Comment: The first problem is that you can't really say anything about the values of the function $f$ in  a point, because Lebesgue-integrable functions are defined up to a set of measure zero. So, at least your identity should take into account this fact.

Second, what happens if you try to deduce your identity for a Lebesgue-integrable but not-Riemann-integrable function?

Comment: @TZakrevskiy: Actually, $f(x)$ is a probability density function and we can assume that it's defined for all $x \in \mathbb{R}.$

Comment: @TZakrevskiy It's not true that Lebesgue integrable functions are defined only up to a set of measure $0.$ They are functions after all.

Comment: @zhw. While you can define them everywhere, from the perspective of Lebesgue integration, if the measure space is complete, then functions that are equal almost everywhere are as good as equal.

Comment: @Ian Really? What about the idea of a Lebesgue point?

Comment: @zhw. OK, that's fair, in that sense we pay attention, but you can modify the function on a set of measure zero and then you just have a different null set of non-Lebesgue points.

Comment: The hypothesis is not "let $f \in L^1$", where $L^1$ is the quotient space of integrable functions under the "equal almost everywhere" equivalence relation and, depending on interpretation, $f$ is either an equivalence class or an unspecified element of its equivalence class. The hypothesis is "let $f$ be a function", so, by definition, it has a specific value at each point in the domain, i.e., $f$ is a particular representative of its equivalence class.

Answer (score 2):

This is not true even for continuous nonnegative $f.$ For $N=1,2,\dots,$  we define $f$ on the disjoint intervals $[N-1/(N^2e^N),[N+1/(N^2e^N)]$ to be an isosceles triangular spike of height $e^N$ centered over this interval. Define $f$ to be $0$ everywhere else. Then $f$ is continuous everywhere, and

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x) \ dx = \sum_{N=2}^{\infty}1/N^2 < \infty.$$

But for each $N,$

$$\sum_{m \in\mathbb{Z}} \frac{1}{N} f \left( \frac{m}{N}\right) > \frac{1}{N}f \left( \frac{N^2}{N} \right) =  \frac{e^N}{N}\to \infty$$

as $N\to \infty.$

Comment: Surely you mean $f$ is a sum of triangular spikes?

Comment: You are using $N$ to define $f$, but then taking the limit of the sum as $N \to \infty$, meaning that $f$ changes with $N$. But in the OP, $f$ is independent of $n$.

Comment: @zhw. Does it hold if you assume some other properties on $f$ like continuously differentiable etc, ? I want to know when can the result hold so it's okay make assumptions about $f$.

Comment: @A.S. Yes you're right. It was a sloppy writing job on my part. I edited it and hope it is clear now.

Comment: @Paul Sinclair I hope the edited answer clears that up.

Comment: @Ashok Vardhan No, smoothness won't help, not even real analyticity. One very useful sufficient condition is to assume $f$ increases to the left of $0$ and decreases to the right of $0.$

Comment: @AshokVardhan: One can simply replace the triangles with appropriately scaled smooth "bump" functions with compact support. I also wanted to mention that if we scale $f$ so that $\int f = 1$ then this example gives us a legitimate probability density function, although not a very congenial one to work with (I think that its moments would all be infinite, for example).

Comment: A real analytic example is

$$f(x) = e^{x^2}[(2+\cos 2\pi x)/3]^{e^{4x^2}},$$

which is harder than looking at triangular spikes, but kind of fun. (Note the huge power $e^{4x^2}$ smashing the thing in brackets down to $0$ except at the integers. That's why it works. Laplace's method shows $\int f < \infty.$)

Answer (score 1):

With the assumption that $f$ is continuous, this holds. WIthout the assumption of continuity it does not in general. For example $$ f(x) = \begin{cases} e^{-x^2} & x - z \in \Bbb Q\\0 & x - z \notin \Bbb Q\end{cases}$$ The limit is positive, but the integral is $0$.

Edit:

As zhw has shown, the expression does not necessarily hold even for continuous $f$. But there are more ways to rescue it than just functions that are monotonic on either side of some point. One trick is simply to reverse the limits: Exchange the limits on $m$ and $n$ and the result holds for continuous functions:

$$\lim_{M\to \infty} \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{m = -M}^M \frac 1 n f\left (\frac{m + z}{n}\right ) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\ dx$$

As I noted in the comments, $f$ is Riemann integrable on finite intervals because it is continuous. The limit on $n$ is just a Riemann sum for the integral $\int_{-M}^M f(x)\ dx$, and therefore must converge to it. Taking the limit as $M \to \infty$ then converges to the full integral over all of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Can you explain the proof for continuous case  ? It would be more helpful if you can explain it in your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Except for the fact that interval is infinite, the sum is not just "Riemann-like", it is an actual Riemann sum. Since the function is continuous and the Lesbegue integral exists, the function is Riemann integrable, with the same integral. However, though his counter-example is broken, zhw is correct that you don't get improper Riemann integrals by taking Riemann sums over all of $\Bbb R$. The Riemann integral is defined by sums only on finite intervals and is on infinite interval only by letting the finite limits grow without bound. I will need to examine it further.

Comment: @AshokVardhan - see the edit for an alternative approach to fixing your formula for continuous functions.

Comment: But how do we justify the swapping of limits. The way I want to prove is the other order of limits right ?

Comment: You don't. The whole point of zhw's construction below is that those limits do not swap. That is why I had to swap them to get this this to hold for continuous functions. I posted this because I considered it possible that whatever your application was, you might be able to use this version instead of the one given. If so, then you at least have a result for continuous functions. If not, then you need stronger conditions on $f$.